# Get Reference to Currently Displayed Card

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

Let’s say I have a `JPanel` named `cards` and it has a layout type of `CardLayout`. Each card in the layout is also of class`JPanel`. How do I get a reference to the `JPanel` that’s currently being displayed in the layout?

Thanks.

Comment: It is the one which you will display... For a better answer, show us some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get a reference to the JPanel that’s currently being displayed in the layout?

There is nothing in the API that allows you to do this, that I'm aware of. So,I extended the CardLayout to provide this information.

Check out [Card Layout Focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/card-layout-focus/) for my implementation that allows you to get this information among other things.

Comment: Thanks. Not surprised that someone would think this to be a useful feature before I did.